# Graph API - adding Schema Extension using .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I need to add custom claims to my Azure B2C users, so I figured the way to do this is to add schema extensions to the User for my directory App with Graph API (beta).

I wrote a simple test for that:

```
SchemaExtension schemaExtension = new SchemaExtension
{
    Id = schemaName,
    Owner = _appClientId.ToString(),
    Description = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(schemaDesc) ? string.Empty : schemaDesc.Trim(),
    TargetTypes = new List<string>
    {
        "User"
    },
    Properties = new List<ExtensionSchemaProperty>
    {
        new ExtensionSchemaProperty
        {
            Name = "isGlobalAdmin",
            Type = "Boolean"
        },
        new ExtensionSchemaProperty
        {
            Name = "isOrganizationAdmin",
            Type = "Boolean"
        }
    }
};

SchemaExtension extension = await GraphClient.SchemaExtensions
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(schemaExtension);
```

First, it didn't work because of lack of permissions. So I created a new user in my directory and added Global Admin role to it. Then I set **Treat application as a public client** to true in the app authentication settings. That fixed permission problem.

But now I have this one:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException : Code: Service_InternalServerError

I tried changing params for the `SchemaExtension` but nothing helps.

How can I make this work?

**API I use - [Microsoft.Graph.Beta](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet)**

### UPDATE - Graph API init

```
private async Task<GraphServiceClient> InitGraphClientWithUserAndPassword()
{
    try
    {
        IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(_appClientId.ToString())
            .WithTenantId(_tenantId.ToString())
            .Build();

        UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication); // scopes

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

        SecureString securePass = new NetworkCredential("", _password).SecurePassword;
        User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
            .WithUsernamePassword(_userEmail, securePass)
            .GetAsync();

        return graphClient;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        const string ERR_MSG = "Could not create GraphAPI client";
        _logger.LogError(ex, ERR_MSG);
        throw new IlgGraphApiException(ERR_MSG, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post which api are you trying to use?

Comment: Added the link to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code. It works fine for Azure AD but gets error **Code: Service_InternalServerError\r\nMessage: Encountered an internal server error.\r\n\r\nInner error\r\n** for Azure AD B2C.

I don't think Microsoft Graph API [Create schemaExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-post-schemaextensions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request-2) is supported for Azure AD B2C currently.

As this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr) says, Custom attributes in Azure AD B2C use [Azure AD Graph API Directory Schema Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions#register-an-extension--). Support for newer Microsoft Graph API for querying Azure AD B2C tenant is still under development.

Comment: I think you're right. The docs are so confusing about Azure B2C and Graph API!