# How to verify a domain so a schema extension can be added to ms graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

My root question is: How do I add a schema extension to ms graph?

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups) describes how to add a schema extension but [misdirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-platform-service-description/domains) the user on how to verify a domain.

So when I tried this:

```
var schemaExtension = new SchemaExtension
{
   Id = "domain_subscriberInfo",
```

The error message received is:

> Your organization must own the namespace domain-name as a part of one of the verified domains.

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) says: "If you don’t have a verified vanity domain, you can just set the id to a schema name (without a domain name prefix), for example, mySchema. Microsoft Graph will assign a string ID for you based on the supplied name, in this format: ext{8-random-alphanumeric-chars}_{schema-name}. For example, extkvbmkofy_mySchema."

But this code:

```
var schemaExtension = new SchemaExtension
{
   Id = "extkvbmkofy_subscriberInfo",
```

Results in this error message:

> Your organization must own the namespace domain-name as a part of one of the verified domains.

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/domain?view=graph-rest-1.0) describes how to check verification but does not describe how to put a domain in a verified state.  I took a guess and tried adding a txt record with text specified in the output of `VerificationDnsRecords` but that is just me guessing and it doesn't work.

Documentation says "For an unverified domain, the isVerified property of the domain is false." I will have to assume isVerified is false because the call to `Verify()` crashes with

> Domain verification failed with the following error: 'Error in DNS verification. code=MissingRecord'.

How do I get past these issues to add a schema extension to ms graph?

Comment: can you please provide the correlation id and timestamp of you are error message

Comment: Status Code: InternalServerError
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Service_InternalServerError
Message: Encountered an internal server error.
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:
 date: 2020-11-20T21:09:44
 request-id: 49230717-1953-47bb-befa-5473ed35f522
 client-request-id: 49230717-1953-47bb-befa-5473ed35f522
ClientRequestId: 49230717-1953-47bb-befa-5473ed35f522

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response can you please let us know you are verified domains is it ends with .com .net,.gov, .edu, and .org

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity ends with .com

Answer (score 0):

See this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-post-schemaextensions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-creating-a-schema-extension-using-just-a-name) to create a schema extension using just a name (rather than a domain namespaced name).

To add a custom domain, add the domain (which is unverified), then get the verificationDnsRecords for the domain you added and use that info to update your domain configuration with your domain registrar.  You can then try to verify.  Sometimes it can take an hour for the DNS to refresh, so verify could fail initially.  You can follow some more visual steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain?context=azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/context/ugr-context) through the Azure Portal.

Calling verify should not get an internal server error.  Can you repro for some fresh client request id and timestamp please?  Our trace logs are only retained for 30 days I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you Dan.  [I've been down this road before](https://old.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/jud07a/why_a_two_hour_job_in_azure_took_two_days_and_i/.).  [See this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395423/graph-api-adding-schema-extension-using-net-core-3-1).